# json_decode limitations?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode the JSON at `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&incslude_rts=0&screen_name=microsoft&count=200&exclude_replies=1&contributor_details=0` with `json_decode()` in PHP (decoding as an associative array, so the second parameter is set to `TRUE`.

The problem is that it seems to not do anything (no error, warning either). The data contains 200 tweets + some extra data about them. If I fetch only let's say 50 tweets, the `json_decode` function runs successfully.

So my question is: is `json_decode` not able to decode large strings?

Edit: my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // $url is the above mentioned URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($content,true));
```

Comment: Should not be a problem. Post your php-code

Comment: I don't know if exists a bug on the lenght, but in PHP < 5.2.3 there was a bug in the depth: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38945 .
Can it be your case?

Comment: Works fine for me (PHP 5.3.6).

Comment: I think Its a problem with your code. Are you fetching remote data properly? May be http transaction is not properly ended. You could download using `wget` and then check if `json_decode` works

Comment: Try `file_get_contents`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Both `wget` and `file_get_contents` are too slow, I benchmarked it and cURL seemed to be the fastest. Yes, my data is fetched correctly. But I've tried it again and it's working now. Maybe it was a temporary problem or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your cURL I suppose. I just tried the following code with the URL you have provided and works just fine:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&incslude_rts=0&screen_name=microsoft&count=200&exclude_replies=1&contributor_details=0';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$content = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(json_decode($content, true));
```